# How to merge small files from existing partitions in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

How to merge existing Partition small files into one large file in one of the Partition .

For example I have a table user1, it contain columns fname,lname and partition column is day.

I have created table by using below  script

CREATE TABLE user1(fname string,lname string) parittioned By (day int);

After inserting data into partion table it will look like below.

```
 fname  lname  day
.....................
AA      AAA   20170201     ....>partition 20170201
BB      BBB   20170201
...................
CC      CCC   20170202    ......>partition 20170202
DD      DDD   20170202
....................
EE      EEE   20170203    .......>partition 20170203
FF      FFF   20170203
.......................
GG      GGG   20170204    ........>partition 20170204         
HH      HHH   20170204
.......................
```

When I execute select query with the help of partition column i.e. day=20170201.

```
select * from user1 where day=20170201;
```

It will give result like below

```
AA      AAA   20170201
BB      BBB   20170201
```

based on above table i want to merge the all small files i.e  day =20170201 and day =20170202 and day=20170203 into partition day=20170203 in my partition table (i.e USer1).i.e. It should look like below.

```
fname  lname  day
.....................
AA      AAA   20170201
BB      BBB   20170201
CC      CCC   20170202    
DD      DDD   20170202
E       EEE   20170203    .......>partition 20170203
FF      FFF   20170203
.......................
GG      GGG   20170204    ........>partition 20170204         
HH      HHH   20170204
.......................
```

can you please suggest on this,How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new table partitioned by new field `partition_day`:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_new(fname string,lname string, day int) parittioned By (partition_day int);
> ```

2. Load data into new table (define your conditions for new partitionsin the `case`  )

> ```
>    insert overwrite table user_new partition (partition_day)
>     select fname,lname, day,
>            case when day <= 20170203 then 20170203
>                 when day >  20170203 then 20170204
>            end as partition_day
>       from user1 ;
> ```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, it will work  for new table but I want to use same existing table. so I  add new column to existing table with the help of  “alter table user1 add columns(partition_day int);”  

New column add with NULL value. Now partition_day contains values “NULL”

But after that I am trying to override  the same table by selecting the same table like below.
“insert overwrite table user1 partition (day)select fname,lname,day as partition_day, case when day <= 20170206 then 20170206 when day > 20170206 then 20170207 end as day from user1”

Comment: Then also  partition_day contains Null values only.
Can please help on this how can set the day value to partition_Day.
Thanks in Advance .